# I want to display the selected radio button on my update page

Tags: php, mysql, sql, radio-button

What did I do wrong here?

Php code for NSO

```
if(!isset($_POST["nso"])) {
$message = "NSO is required";
}else {
$message = "Did not submit NSO";
}
```

Select

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM student_prof where studentID = '$id' ") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
```

Html code

```
<input type="radio" name="nso" value="Submitted" <?php if(isset($_POST['nso']) && $_POST['nso']=="Submitted") echo 'checked="checked"' ?>> Submitted<br>
<input type="radio" name="nso" value="Not Submitted" <?php if(isset($_POST['nso']) && $_POST['nso']=="Not Submitted") echo 'checked="checked"' ?>>Not Submitted
```

Comment: I don't understand the code snippet for select

Comment: that's the code where I selected all the information from the students.

Comment: But how that relates to the question?

Comment: Because I don't know what I did wrong and maybe it can help if I include it with my question.

Comment: It doesn't help; from what I can tell, the inputs should be rendered correctly, with the appropriate `checked` attribute set if the `$_POST['nso']` is set correctly

Comment: give me the all code context

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE student_prof SET nso='".$_POST['nso']."'  WHERE studentID='".$_POST['studentID']."' " ;
 
mysql_select_db('db_name');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
  }
   echo "<center><p>Updated data successfully</p></center>\n";

   mysql_close($conn);
}else {
 ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code

```
<input type="radio" name="nso" value="Submitted" <?php if(isset($_POST['nso']) && $_POST['nso']=="Submitted") echo "checked" ?>> Submitted<br>
<input type="radio" name="nso" value="Not Submitted" <?php if(isset($_POST['nso']) && $_POST['nso']=="Not Submitted") echo "checked" ?>>Not Submitted
```

Based on select query

```
<input type="radio" name="nso" value="Submitted" <?php if(isset($row['nso']) && $row['nso']=="Submitted") echo "checked" ?>> Submitted<br>
<input type="radio" name="nso" value="Not Submitted" <?php if(isset($row['nso']) && $row['nso']=="Not Submitted") echo "checked" ?>>Not Submitted
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot! :)